# PHP strlen(str) not working

Tags: php, html, forms, strlen

I have a form on my website that takes input from a text area and processes it one way if it is empty (strlen = 0) and another if it has text in it.
Here is part of the form:

```
<form name='contact' action='contact.php' method='post'>
    ...
    Message*<br />
    <textarea name='msg' rows='10' cols='70' maxlength='2048'><?php echo $msg ?></textarea><br />
    ...
    <input type='submit' value='Send!' id='subby' name='fatk' style='height:60px; width:300px;' />
</form>
```

Now the PHP code:

```
$msg = isset($_POST['msg'])?safeString($_POST['msg']):'';
$msg = substr($msg,0,2048);
if (strlen($msg) == 0)
    echo "<h1>Test failed</h1>";
else { ... }
```

Here's the `safestring(str)` method:

```
function safeString($str) {
    htmlentities($str);
    htmlspecialchars($str);
}
```

Every time I submit the form, no matter how much or how little I put in the msg textarea, it always says it's empty (by echoing TEST FAILED). Also, do you know anything else I should add to my `safestring()` function to make my forms more secure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not returning *anything* from `safeString`.

Apart from that, what `safeString` does is redundant (`htmlentities` is a superset of `htmlspecialchars`, and the latter does the job of protecting against XSS).

Finally, you should really *not* be doing this sanitization when accepting input but only when you are producing output.

Put toghether, your code should look more like

```
$msg = isset($_POST['msg']) ? $_POST['msg'] :'';
if ($msg == '')
    echo "<h1>Test failed</h1>";
else {
    echo "Received value: ".htmlspecialchars($msg);
}
```

You should also *definitely* specify the input's encoding (see third parameter of `htmlspecialchars`).

Comment: this is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: So I should use only `htmlspecialchars`?

Comment: @tereško: Give a man a moment to expand the answer, will you?